# MySQL Order by, then Update Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `categories` which contains the columns ID & ParentID I would like to add a field called Level, which states which level in the category tree each category is. 
I think i found my solution but it is in sql not mysql. So i have been converting it to the correct syntax. However, i think im missing a step. So, here is my code:

```
 ALTER TABLE categories DROP Level;

 ALTER TABLE categories ADD Level INT NULL;

 UPDATE categories 
SET Level = 0
WHERE ParentID IS NULL;

 UPDATE categories AS A
    INNER JOIN categories B ON A.ParentID = B.ID
    SET A.Level = B.Level + 1
 WHERE A.Level IS NULL AND
          B.Level IS NOT NULL;
```

I think the problem may lie in the fact that in my DB The order of the categories do not come in any specific order, what i mean is as follows:

```
ID  ParentID
2   NULL 0
4   55
7   2
.....more categories
55  2
```

So what i would like it do do is:

```
ID  Parent  Level
2   NULL    0
3   55      2
7   2       1
....
55  2       1
```

However, i think, but i might be wrong, is that i need to either order by ParentID first before i do the last operation, or my query is missformed.

I am not getting any errors however, but just not getting the results i am expecting this is what im getting;

```
ID  Parent  Level
2   NULL    0
3   55      NULL
7   2       1
....
55  2       1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it is working perfectly.  What happens when you run the query again?  It only updates records when the parent's level is known.  You may have to run this query as many times as you have levels.  For instance, is record #3 updated after you run this a 3rd time?

Comment: How simple. I think i just needed to run it one more time, but before i was running the entire script over again, instead of just the last part.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how many levels do u have?
If they are 3 levels than u can do it like this

```
ALTER TABLE categories DROP Level;
ALTER TABLE categories ADD Level INT NULL;

UPDATE categories SET Level = 0 WHERE ParentID IS NULL;
UPDATE categories SET level = 1 where parentID = 2; 
UPDATE categories SET level = 2 where parentID > 2;
```